# How much free space should I leave for the OS to work seamlessly without any lags?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, storage

I want to know how much free space should be left on the internal phone storage for the operating system to  work without any lags.

[image]

Comment: I think that system already have free space for better work so you don't need to left space in internal storage